# How do I use Core Motion to output magnetometer data using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-motion, magnetometer

I am having trouble outputting the data for the magnetometer, accelerometer and gyroscope using Core Motion with SwiftUI. I'm assuming my problem has something to do with the startMagnetometerUpdates().

I've tried using source code found here on stack overflow, as well as on GitHub/google. The problem is all the code I'm finding uses UIKit instead of SwiftUI. Is it possible to implement this without using UIKit?

```
import CoreMotion

let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
var x = 0.0; var y = 0.0; var z = 0.0

    func magnet() {
  motionManager.magnetometerUpdateInterval = 1/60
  motionManager.startMagnetometerUpdates()
if let magnetometerData = motionManager.magnetometerData {
    x = magnetometerData.magneticField.x
    y = magnetometerData.magneticField.y
    z = magnetometerData.magneticField.z
}
}

struct Magnetometer: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Magnetometer Data")
                Text("X: \(x)")
                Text("Y: \(y)")
                Text("Z: \(z)")
            }
        }
    }

struct Magnetometer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Magnetometer()
    }
}
```

The output should just display the x, y and z values for the sensor and update on an interval of 1/60. The current output is 0.00000 for every value, which is because I set each variable to 0 already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with your code.

Your first problem is that you need a binding between your model data and your view - By creating a binding, the view will be updated automatically when the model changes.

The second problem is that you are only accessing the magnetometer data once via `motionManager.magnetometerData` rather than setting up a closure to monitor updates via `startMagnetometerUpdates(to:withHandler:)`.

You can use `ObservableObject` from the `Combine` framework and `@ObservedObject` in your view to create the appropriate binding.

Start by creating a class to wrap your motion manager:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import CoreMotion

class MotionManager: ObservableObject {

    private var motionManager: CMMotionManager

    @Published
    var x: Double = 0.0
    @Published
    var y: Double = 0.0
    @Published
    var z: Double = 0.0


    init() {
        self.motionManager = CMMotionManager()
        self.motionManager.magnetometerUpdateInterval = 1/60
        self.motionManager.startMagnetometerUpdates(to: .main) { (magnetometerData, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            if let magnetData = magnetometerData {
                self.x = magnetData.magneticField.x
                self.y = magnetData.magneticField.y
                self.z = magnetData.magneticField.z
            }

        }

    }
}
```

This class conforms to `ObservableObject` and `@Publish`es its three properties, x,y and z.

Simply assigning new values to these properties in the magnetometer update closure will cause the publisher to fire and update any observers.

Now, in your view, you can declare an `@ObservedObject` for your motion manager class and bind the properties.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject
    var motion: MotionManager

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Magnetometer Data")
            Text("X: \(motion.x)")
            Text("Y: \(motion.y)")
            Text("Z: \(motion.z)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(motion: MotionManager())
    }
}
```

Note that you will need to pass an instance of `MotionManager` in your `SceneDelegate.swift` file:

```
let contentView = ContentView(motion: MotionManager())
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Combine to build a class to provide the data:

```
import Combine

public class MagneicFieldProvider: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    public let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<CMMagneticField,Never>()

    public private(set) var magneticField: CMMagneticField = CMMagneticField() {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send(newValue)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        motionManager.stopMagnetometerUpdates()
    }

    private let motionManager: CMMotionManager

    public override init(){
        self.motionManager = CMMotionManager()
        super.init()
        motionManager.magnetometerUpdateInterval = 1/60
    }

    public func startUpdates() {
        motionManager.startMagnetometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { this, that in
            if let magneticField = self.motionManager.magnetometerData?.magneticField {
                self.magneticField = magneticField
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it in your View:

```
struct MagnetometerView: View {

    @ObservedObject var magnetometer = MagneicFieldProvider()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Magnetometer Data")
            Text("X: \(magnetometer.magneticField.x)")
            Text("Y: \(magnetometer.magneticField.y)")
            Text("Z: \(magnetometer.magneticField.z)")
        }   .onAppear(perform: { self.magnetometer.startUpdates() })
    }
}
```